# Can't connect mysql workbench to mysql even though I can connect normally through the terminal

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, manjaro

I recently installed mysql and mysql workbench on my manjaro machine. As for mysql itself, it works perfectly. I can start the service, connect using terminal and do my usual work without any trouble.

The problem is that mysql workbench can't, for the life of me, connect to mysql. Always returning the same **your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the mysql server at 127.0.0.1:3306: SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it** error.

Even when I try the **Rescan servers** option on mysql workbench it returns **No servers were found**.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Use SSL" to "No" while creating the connection? Or is this happening immediately after starting Workbench?

Comment: I actually have been trying to do that but my workbench version doesn't have that option in it. It only has **require**, **require and verify CA** and **require and verify identity**